# $P(X=k)=\frac{a_k\theta^k}{g(\theta)}$: What is $g$ called in relation to $X$?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, taylor-expansion

If $g(\theta)=\underset{k=0,1,2..}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} a_k\theta^k$ is a Taylor series then, we can generate a probability distribution such that
$$P(X=k)=\frac{a_k\theta^k}{g(\theta)}.$$
Then, $X$ is said to have a power series distribution.

> Question: What is "$g$" called in relation to $X$? Is it the probability generating function?

Comment: $g$ is a normalizing constant. It is needed for sum of probabilities to be equal to $1$.

Comment: @NCh got it! Also, the expression for the pmf, $P(X=k)$ is okay, right?

Comment: It is okay if $a_k\geq 0$ for all $k$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$g$  is a normalizing constant. It is needed for sum of probabilities to be equal to $1$. The equation for $P(X=k)$ is okay if $a_k\ge0$ for all $k$.

[answered by [@NCh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/413376/nch) in the comments section]